# What determines CRAN binary compatibility?

Tags: r, cran

CRAN has binary versions of packages for Windows and macOS. However, `install.packages()` will only use these when running in the official CRAN R distribution. If one uses a different R distribution (e.g. from Homebrew or MacPorts on macOS) or compiles R from sources oneself, then `install.packages()` will not download binaries and will instead compile all packages from sources.

Questions:

- Why does `install.packages()` refuse to get binaries from CRAN when running in a non-official R distribution? I assume there is some concern about binary compatibility, and I am looking to gain some technical insight into the reason for that.
- How is binary compatibility verified? How does `install.packages()` tell whether binaries can be used or not?
- What is required to produce a separate R distribution that is (a) compatible with CRAN binaries (b) will be detected as compatible by `install.packages()`?

Comment: can you see what `R.version$os` is in these different platforms?

Comment: Can you install the binaries with e.g. `install.packages("dplyr", type = "mac.binary"`? What do you get if you type `getOption("pkgType")` into the console? If you run `options(pkgType = "both")` then do a normal `install.packages("dplyr")` does this give you the binary?

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, it is different, but that does not necessarily mean that this is how `install.packages()` makes the decision. In CRAN R on macOS I see `darwin17.0`, as it was compiled for macOS 10.13 or later. In MacPorts's R I see `darwin18.7.0` as that's the identifier of macOS 10.14.6 which I am using.

Comment: @AllanCameron `type = "mac.binary"` installs the binary version. `getOption("pkgType")` is `"source"`. After setting `options(pkgType = "both")`, `install.packages()` issues this error: `type == "both" can only be used on Windows or a CRAN build for macOS`. This makes it clear that the restriction is intentional.

Comment: @Szabolcs so why can't you use `install.packages()` with `type = "mac.binary"`?

Comment: @AllanCameron That could be part of an answer to my question that you might want to write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs in `?install.packages` regarding the `type` parameter:

> Possible values of `type` are (currently) "source", "mac.binary", and "win.binary": the appropriate binary type where supported can also be selected as "binary".

The default setting for `type` is `getOption("pkgType")`. This option seems to be defaulted to `"source"` in non-CRAN builds, and if you try to set the option to `"both"`, (which would be the default on CRAN builds), then `install.packages` will complain. You could set the option to `"mac.binary"`, or bypass the options altogether by using the `type` parameter.

So, to install the latest MacOS binary for, say, dplyr, you could do:

```r
install.packages("dplyr", type = "mac.binary")
```

or

```r
options(pkgType = "mac.binary")

install.packages("dplyr")
```

Note this will also install the dependencies of the installed package.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! It may be useful to mention that this will install binaries not only for dplyr but also all its dependencies.